# Utilizando JSP e JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

Estou começando a mexer com JSP. Mas já utilizo JAVA há algum tempo.

Tenho o arquivo index.jsp que é minha página e tenho meu indexJava.java que é o programa em si.
Gostaria de saber como faço para unir os dois. Por exemplo, quando clico em um botão, ele envia uma variável para o .java e executa determinado método que está relacionado com este botão.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quem faz o meio de campo é o Servlet.

Primeiramente, vamos dar nome as coisas. Nenhum projeto é pequeno demais que não possa ser usado o padrão de projeto MVC, que é a abreviação de Model - View - Controller, e isso quer dizer que seu projeto deve ter esses três elementos.

Sua aplicação deve estar assim:

> **Model:** IndexJava.java
>   <sup>(tomei a liberdade de capitalizar a primeira letra da sua classe para seguir o padrão de nomenclatura do Java que diz que classes devem começar com maiúsculos)</sup>
>   **View:** resultado.jsp
>   <sup>não confunda com seu index, que pode ser .html</sup>
>   **Controller:** MeuController.java
>   <sup>(apenas um exemplo de nome, sugiro que você coloque algo mais intuitivo dependendo do que se trata sua aplicação)</sup>

O Controller é o que chamamos de Servlet, e o Servlet é uma classe Java. No exemplo acima chamei o Servlet de MeuController.java. Ele, sendo uma classe Java, consegue se comunicar normalmente com seu Model, como disse que sabe Java há algum tempo creio que não terá dificuldades nessa parte.

Para uma classe Java ser um Servlet ela deve estender HttpServlet (ou alguma outra classe que é uma subclasse na hierarquia da interface Servlet, mas isso não vem ao caso). Aconselho colocar essa classe em um pacote separado do seu Model para ficar bem clara a distinção.

Seu Servlet, por ter estendido a classe HttpServlet terá a possibilidade de sobrescrever os métodos `doGet()` e `doPost()` (dentre outros, que geralmente não são usados), que tem os parametros HttpServletRequest e HttpServletResponse. Esses dois parâmetros recebem dois objetos como argumento, e quem chama esse método é o Container (Tomcat), que também é o responsável por criar os objetos em questão, consequentemente, o Container tem uma referência deles, e ao atualizá-los em sua classe Servlet o Container terá conhecimento dessas modificação. É assim que você comunica suas classes Model com seu View.

Você ainda precisa fazer com que seu View saiba onde o endereço do seu Servlet, uma forma flexível de fazer isso é mapeando o caminho do Servlet através do Deployment Descriptor, que é um arquivo XML.

Para que sua página inicial se comunique com os métodos `doGet()` e `doPost()` do seu Servlet você deve fazer um `<form>` em um arquivo .html e submeter direcionando para seu Servlet, exemplo:

```
<form method=POST action=SelectCoffee.do>
```

Ao clicar no botão `submit` você enviará uma requisição do tipo POST para seu Servlet, logo, seu método `doPost()` será acionado, se você não tiver implementado o `doPost()` no seu Servlet você receberá um erro ao tentar submeter o formulário.

Se você fizer seu form assim:

```
<form action=SelectCoffee.do>
```

Ele será do tipo GET, que é o tipo padrão. Para funcionar corretamente você precisará ter implementado o método `doGet()` em seu Servlet.

SelectCoffeee.do é o nome que eu escolhi dar para o Servlet, ele é redirecionado para a classe indicada no Deployment Descriptor.

Traduzindo toda essa teoria em prática, aqui vai um exemplo para você usar como guia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse modelo eu criei com base do capítulo 3 do livro "Head First - Servlets & JSP", que é meu objeto de estudo.

E o conteúdo dos arquivos é:

**CoffeeExpert.java**

```
package com.example.model;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class CoffeeExpert extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public List<String> getBrands(String type) {
        List<String> brands = new ArrayList<>();
        if(type.toLowerCase().equals("dark")) {
            brands.add("Toco");
            brands.add("3 Corações");
            brands.add("Pilão");
        }
        else if(type.toLowerCase().equals("cappuccino")) {
            brands.add("3 Corações");
            brands.add("Nescafé");
        }
        else if(type.toLowerCase().equals("expresso")) {
            brands.add("Do bar");
            brands.add("Da loja de carros");
        }
        return brands;
    }
}
```

**CoffeeSelect.java**

```
package com.example.web;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.example.model.CoffeeExpert;

public class CoffeeSelect extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String t = request.getParameter("type");
        CoffeeExpert ce = new CoffeeExpert();
        List<String> result = ce.getBrands(t);

        //--- LET THE FUN BEGIN! ---//
        request.setAttribute("styles", result);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**web.xml** (deployment descriptor)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Ch3 Coffee</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.web.CoffeeSelect</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Ch3 Coffee</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SelectCoffee.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>form.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align=center>Coffee Selection Page</h1>
    <form method=GET action=SelectCoffee.do>
        <p>Select coffee type:</p>
        Type:
        <select name=type size=1>
        <option>Dark
        <option>Cappuccino
        <option>Expresso
        </select>
        <center><input type=submit></center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Meu JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align=center>Coffee Recomendations JSP</h1>
    <p>
        <%
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<String> styles = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("styles");
            for(String s: styles) {
                out.print("<p>Try > " + s + "</p>");
            }
        %>
    </p>
</body>
```

<sup>PS: no livro era Beer ao invés de Coffee, mas eu mudei por não achar muito apropriado em um ambiente de trabalho :)</sup>

---

#### Recebendo um vetor no Servlet

No exemplo acima eu usei:

```
String t = request.getParameter("type");
```

Para receber o valor do select que está no html inicial:

```
<select name=type size=1>
```

Para pegar um vetor ao invés de um valor único basicamente você deve trocar o `getParameter()` por `getParameterValues()`. Veja exemplo:

```
<form method=GET action=Vector.do>
    <p>Select more than one option:</p>
    <input type=checkbox name=info value="opcao 1">op1
    <input type=checkbox name=info value="segunda opcao">op2
    <input type=checkbox name=info value=terceira>op3
    <input type=checkbox name=info value="ultima opcao">op4
    <center><input type=submit></center>
</form>
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String[] info = req.getParameterValues("info");
    for(String s: info) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Selecionando as quatro opções o programa imprime no console:

> opcao 1
>   segunda opcao
>   terceira
>   ultima opcao

Repare que eu adicionei mais um Servlet no Deployment Descriptor, e sua URL é "Vector.do".

Comment: Vlw pelos ensinamentos Math. Ja me deu uma ajuda. 
Agora tenho os seguintes arquivos context.xml , index.jsp , Extrair.java (minha classe mesmo), NewServlet.java .
Mas ainda não entendi como vou passar uma variável que está no index.jsp e conseguir usa-la no Extrair.java

Comment: @user7569 no caso seu index.jsp foi representado no meu exemplo como form.html, pelo menos pelo que eu entendi. Veja que você tem que fazer uma submissão do tipo GET ou do tipo POST para seu Servlet, daí no método doGet() ou do doPost() do seu Servlet vc consegue se comunicar normalmente com a classe Extrair.java. Entendeu?

Comment: @user7569 percebi que faltava na minha resposta um pedaço importante da comunicação entre a pagina inicial e o Servlet, eu fiz uma ediçao adicionando essas explicações. Se preferir ver apenas o que mudei nessa edição [clique aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/22578/revisions)

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado pela ajuda Math. Estou començando a ver uma luz no fim do túnel. haha
A minha dúvida agora é a seguinte, eu passo da minha página html/jsp para meu Servlet uma string e uma lista com alguns valores de checkbox (ou seja, um vetorzinho com os valores das opções selecionadas). Então meu Servlet recebe u m string e um vetor. Como utilizo eles?
Eu consigo ve-los no link pois estou usando GET, mas não sei como separa-los para poder mexer com eles.

Comment: @user7569 bom, para receber os parametros no Servlet você faz através do `request.getParameter("nomeParam")`, no meu exemplo acima está `String t = request.getParameter("type");` que é o nome do elemento select no html. Agora, para ser bem sincero, nunca passei um vetor, tenho que fazer uns testes aqui para não falar besteira. Como você está gerando esse vetor no seu html?

Comment: Estou usando assim <input type="checkbox" name="info[]" value="4"/>
Então as opções marcadas serão enviadas via GET, e a variável que preciso também está sendo enviada.
O fim do meu link está assim, sendo "teste" a string que passa do jsp para servlet:
NewServlet?teste=Extrair.pdf&info[]=1&info[]=3

Comment: @Pacíficão eu editei minha resposta mostrando como pegar um vetor, ao invés de um valor único. Para seu caso você terá que combinar as duas formas, hora vc vai usar o `getParameter()` para pegar a variavel "teste" e hora vai usar `getParameterValues()` para pegar o vetor.

Comment: +1 pelo tutorial, muito bom mesmo!

Comment: @Math muito obrigado... mas não faço ideia de como irei alternar o getParameter() e o getParameterValues(). Como passo os dois juntos, como irei alternar? Faço isso no servlet ou já na minha aplicação (.java)??

Comment: @Pacíficão não é alternar, é combinar. Em uma linha você coloca `String[] info = req.getParameterValues("info");` em outra linha um `String t = request.getParameter("type");`, logo, você terá suas variáveis `t` e `info` carregadas com os valores trazidos do html.

Comment: acho q nao me expressei bem @Math
No seu programa, o método doGET é o responsável pela passagem. Porém, eu nao posso ter dois métodos doGET. Preciso de um para o getParameter e outro para o getParameterValues ??

Comment: @Pacíficão não é possível ter dois doGet() em um mesmo Servlet. Vai ficar tudo dentro de um mesmo método doGet(). Você pode usar os métodos getParameterValues() e getParameter() em cima de um msm request, por exemplo: `String[] info = request.getParameterValues("info[]"); String teste = request.getParameter("teste");` Note que eu usei os nomes que você usou no seu exemplo [nesse comentário aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22558/utilizando-jsp-e-java/22578?noredirect=1#comment42395_22578)

Comment: @Math mais uma vez agradeço pela paciência e pela ajuda. Esta parte ficou redonda. :D
Mas agora estou com outro problema :|
no meu .jsp eu tenho um input file, q preciso pegar um arquivo e no meu .java eu preciso abri-lo e pegar o conteudo desse arquivo. Porém, eu havia pensado em somente pegar o que é passado pela url, como no exemplo citado anteriormente:
NewServlet?teste=Extrair.pdf&info[]=1&info[]=3
Mas quando chega no meu .java ele não reconhece isso como um caminho e sim como um string (meio obvio e eu nao pensei nisso). Como faço para passar um arquivo ou o caminho do arquivo?

Comment: @Pacíficão que bom que pude ajudar :) Sobre a sua segunda dúvida, me parece que está se distanciando um pouco da dúvida criada nesse tópico aqui. Aconselho você a criar uma nova pergunta explicando com detalhes o que precisa, pois o espaço do comentário é meio curto e não dá para responder tudo aqui, além do mais mantemos a organização do site o que torna possível que visitantes futuros com dúvidas similares possam facilmente encontrar a resposta para o que procuram. Tenho ctz que você terá a resposta para essa duvida bem facilmente desse jeito que lhe falei. Abraço.

Answer (score 3):

Os servlets são responsáveis por processar acessos a uma dada URL. Sendo assim, você precisa criar um servlet para processar as requisições que serão feitas à URL para o qual o seu botão aponta.

No código abaixo, por exemplo. Todos os acessos à URL http://meusite.com/home serão processados pelo servlet definido.

```
@WebServlet("/home")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // processar requisições GET aqui.
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // processar requisições POST aqui.
    }
}
```

Você não precisa, necessariamente, sobrescrever os métodos listados acima. Existem outras formas de processar as requisições feitas à URL atribuída ao servlet. Pra entender melhor que métodos são esses, recomendo que você dê uma olhada na [documentação da classe HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/servlet/package-summary.html-summary.html).

Comment: Vale a pena informar que se quiser gerar HTML no Servlet, não precisa ficar concatenando Strings: basta dar um forward para um JSP no final do doGet (`request.getRequestDispatcher(«página»).forward(request, response);`). No final do doPost, o recomendável é usar um redirect para um GET (para que, se o usuário atualizar a página resultante, não a aplicação repita a operação)

Comment: Outra coisa importantíssima com servlets: não use variáveis de instância, pois elas são compartilhadas por várias requisições. Use apenas variáveis locais ou parâmetros de métodos. Se ficar difícil garantir isso, instancie um outro objeto para cada requisição e faça todo o processamento lá.