# O que é um servlet e para que serve?

Tags: java, servlet

Já ouvi muito a respeito do termo `servlet`, porém, ainda não consegui entender. O que realmente é um `servlet`? Para que serve? Qual a sua aplicabilidade na prática?

Comment: Já usou alguma outra linguagem para web além de java?

Comment: Eu comecei a estudar java para web a pouco tempo, ainda estou me adaptando a essa nova forma de programar para web utilizando java. Tenho mais experiência com java para desktop, agora para voltado para plataforma web é um ambiente novo que estou conhecendo

Comment: Sistemas web funcionam bem diferentes dos desktop. Basicamente o que acontece é uma troca de mensagens entre o cliente(um navegador por exemplo) e o servidor, essa conversa ocorre atráves do protocolo http, e sim isso é feito com texto puro! então a linguagem seja o java, c#, php lê essas informações(cabeçalho) e popula alguns objetos/oferece funções para manipulação. `request` é uma solicitação do cliente, pode ser o enviao de um login ou o click em link e `response` é nome dado a resposta do servidor. Teve que ser breve a explicação xD.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação @rray! Se não for pedir muito, vc poderia me dar uma dica por onde devo começar a estudar sobre este tipo de plataforma?

Comment: Independente da tecnologica saiba como funciona o protocolo http, ciclo de vida, métodos os principais são get e post existem outros, veja os cabecalhos, como manter estado entre o cliente e servidor. Esqueci de comentar o http é um protocolo sem estado. Sabendo isso vc consegue trabalhar com qualque linguaguem pois os conceitos são os mesmo.

Comment: Relacionado: [Utilizando JSP e JAVA](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22558/3117)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Servlets são classes Java, desenvolvidas de acordo com uma estrutura bem definida que quando instaladas e configuradas em um Servidor que implemente um Servlet Container, podem tratar requisições recebidas de clientes Web, como por exemplo os Browsers (Internet Explorer® e Mozilla Firefox®).
>
> Ao receber uma requisição, um Servlet pode capturar os parâmetros desta requisição, efetuar qualquer processamento inerente a uma classe Java, e devolver uma página HTML. - **Retirado do Devmedia**.

São basicamente módulos de software que são executados em um servidor web para atender as requisições de aplicações cliente e prestar-lhes algum tipo de serviço.

Ou seja, quando você recebe sua requisição na view, você precisa receber essa requisição, processar de alguma forma e enviar uma resposta. A Servlet recebe sua requisição, processa ou envia pra alguém processar e então retorna a resposta pra onde necessitar.

Comment: Fiquei com uma dúvida, o que seria um Container @guiandmag?

Comment: É uma abstração, um componente que engloba vários componentes pra dar funcionalidade, https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(tipo_de_dado_abstrato), como exemplo no mundo Java, temos o Tomcat, um container(componente) que engloba outros componentes(Servlet) para dar real funcionalidade a tudo.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado @guiandmag

Answer (score 8):

Servlet é uma classe do java para trabalhar com desenvolvimento web apesar de não ser desenvolvida especialmente para isso.

Nessa classe, são feitas as manipulações das requisições, dois membros importantes são o `request`(entrada normalmente) e o `response`(saída).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Teste extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Teste() {
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O Servlet é uma tecnologia que a plataforma Java fornece aos desenvolvedores web como um mecanismo simples e consistente para estender a funcionalidade de um servidor web e para acessar os sistemas de negócios existentes. Servlets Java é o que torna muitos aplicativos web possíveis, são eles que são responsáveis por gerar as paginas dinamicamente conforme requisição do usuário. Resumindo, o objetivo é receber chamadas HTTP, processá-las e devolver uma resposta ao cliente.

Você pode ler uma explicação ótima [aqui](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/servlets/#5-2-servlets).

Fontes:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html