# Para que servem os arquivos JSP no desenvolvimento Java Web no Back-End?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jsp, back-end

Estava em um projeto da minha faculdade onde estava usando o arquivo **JSP** para enviar os dados de um formulário **HTML** para o banco de dados **MYSQL**. Após aprender como criar objetos em **Java**, responsáveis por armazenar os dados do formulário e enviá-lo para o **JSP**, me surgiu uma dúvida... Os arquivos **JSP** são apenas usados como intermediários para a comunicação entre o *Front-end* e o *Back-end* ? Que outras aplicações eles podem desempenhar no cenário do *Back-end*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de falar **`para que servem os arquivos JSP no desenvolvimento Java Web no Back-End`**, primeiro temos que saber que em um sistema web teremos requisições (request) feitas pelo cliente e respostas (response) feitas pelo servidor, ou seja, um servidor web recebe uma solicitação e devolve algo para o cliente. Esse *"algo"* pode ser várias coisas, como, por exemplo, um **JSON**, um **PDF**, uma página **HTML**, etc... Veja: [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174116/como-o-protocolo-http-processa-as-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

O problema é quando você precisa criar uma página HTML dinâmica, nesse caso a página não existe no servidor, você terá que criar na hora e devolver na resposta (response), ou seja, o cliente faz uma requisição de uma página que não existe, com base nas informações recebidas na request você cria a página e devolve para o cliente.

No Java temos a classe **`HttpServlet`** que é responsável por tratar essas requisições. Veja: [O que é um Servlet e para que serve?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91620/o-que-%C3%A9-um-servlet-e-para-que-serve)

Então para obter dados da requisição ou para adicionar algo na resposta, nós usamos um Servlet. Então se quisermos devolver uma página HTML para o cliente, temos que coloca-la na resposta. Se a página for dinâmica, então vamos ter que colocar na resposta de forma dinâmica e vamos ter que fazer isso usando um **Servlet**. Se você pesquisar um pouco, verá que escrever um HTML em um Servlet é horrível, tudo fica bagunçado. Então aí que entra o **`JSP`**, por baixo dos panos ele vai virar um servlet, ou seja, no lugar de você escrever tudo em uma classe Java que herda um **`HttpServlet`**, você escreve em um arquivo *`.jsp`* e esse arquivo torna-se um servlet. Basicamente o seu JSP vira um código fonte em Java, então é compilado em um *`.class`*. Dessa forma fica mais fácil de se trabalhar e dar manutenção

**OBS**: JSP, **JavaServer Page**, é uma linguagem de **script**

> Os arquivos JSP são apenas usados como intermediários para a comunicação entre o Front-end e o Back-end?

Não sei se *intermediários* seria a palavra certa, pois ele faz parte do back end, quando a aplicação for executada ele será uma classe Java, ele não é um agente externo, o JSP é uma linguagem de script para criar páginas dinâmicas ao invés de fazer isso em uma classe Java de forma direta.

> Que outras aplicações eles podem desempenhar no cenário do Back-end?

A função dele é apenas criar páginas dinâmicas, mas você pode escrever Java nele pois no final o JSP vai virar uma classe Java, com base nisso e sabendo como a classe Java será, você pode, por exemplo, incorporar alguma lógica de controle ou tentar fazer outras coisas com o JSP além de HTML dinâmicos, mas só porque é possível não quer dizer que devemos fazer... Lembre-se que o recomendado é usar o JSP para gerar HTML dinâmico e delegar lógica às classes Java